# SAS catx function removes spaces

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a dataset which has 1 column and n rows like this:

Dataset1:

```
Column1
--------
AAA AAA
BBB BBB
CCC CCC
DDD DDD
EEE EEE
```

I want to make from this data 1 row like:

"AAA AAA"n "BBB BBB"n "CCC CCC"n "DDD DDD"n "EEE EEE"n

I will make this in macro.

I used like catx function. But the function removes spaces from data..

I used do loop like this :

```
 .
 .
 .
 .
data _NULL_;
          if &I^=1 then do;
            frstclmn=&frstclmn||""""||"&clmn"||""""||"n ";
        end;
        run;
 .
 .
 .
```

But I couldn't assing a variable in do lop in data statement with itself.

How can I do ? Thanks

Edit:

```
%MACRO result;
        data _NULL_;
          set &LIB_NAME..column_list;
          retain namelist;
          length namelist $5000;
            namelist=catx(' ',namelist,cats('"',name,'"n'));
        run;

---how can I use "namelist" variable here ? out of data statement.---

%MEND result;
```

This code runs perfectly. Now I want to use this namelist variable out of this data statement. If I print like this %put &namelist=; It show wrong result in macro. I want to use this variable result in macro other statement.

Comment: I have no idea where macros come into this, you want help with this in macro language you'll need to provide more code than that.

Comment: And - yes, catx removes spaces, that's sort of one of its purposes.  You haven't really even explained what you're doing with CATX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sql` method `data _null_` shows above is the better method, but if you're going to do it in data step, use `' '` as your delimiter.

```
    data _NULL_;
      set sashelp.class;
      retain namelist;
      length namelist $500;
      namelist=catx(' ',namelist,cats('"',name,'"n'));
      put namelist=;
    run;
```

Of course you could use `quote`, or `nliteral`, both to better effect.

```
    data _NULL_;
      set sashelp.class;
      retain namelist;
      length namelist $500;
      namelist=catx(' ',namelist,nliteral(name));
      put namelist=;
    run;
```

Comment: This code run , thank you. But How can I use this namelist variable out of data statement.. When I run in macro %put &namelist=; it show wrong result.

Comment: `CALL SYMPUTX` to make a macro variable out of it, if you're trying to do that. But you really should explain more in the question.  And consider the other answer, it's going to more readily give you your result I think.

Comment: I am sorry for missing information. Can you explain please how can I use out of statement ?

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear to me what output you seek.  Perhaps this will give you some hints.

```
data names;
   input name $32.;
   cards;
AAA AAA
BBB BBB
CCC CCC
DDD DDD
EEE EEE
;;;;
   run;
proc sql noprint;
   select nliteral(name) into :namelist separated by ' ' from names;
   quit;
   run;
%put NOTE: &=namelist;

NOTE: NAMELIST="AAA AAA"N "BBB BBB"N "CCC CCC"N "DDD DDD"N "EEE EEE"N
```

Comment: Nice! I've never seen the `nliteral` function before.  I've been doing things the hard way =(

Comment: @user3646666 That comment doesn't make sense.